# Odd Linq behavior with IList / IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got the following code:

```
    public IList<IProductViewModel> ChildProducts { get; set; }
    public IList<IProductViewModel> GiftItems { get; set; }
    public IList<IProductViewModel> PromoItems { get; set; }

    public IList<IProductViewModel> NonGiftItems
    {
        get
        {
            return NonPromoItems.Except(GiftItems, new ProductViewModelComparer()).ToList();
        }
    }

    public IList<IProductViewModel> NonPromoItems
    {
        get
        {
            return ChildProducts.Where(p => !p.IsPromotion).ToList();
        }
    }
```

ProductViewModelComparer:

```
public class ProductViewModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<IProductViewModel>
{

    #region IEqualityComparer<IProductViewModel> Members

    public bool Equals(IProductViewModel x, IProductViewModel y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return String.Equals(x.ProductId, y.ProductId);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IProductViewModel obj)
    {
        return obj.ProductId.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So basically, `NonPromoItems` is `(ChildProducts - PromoItems)` and `NonGiftItems` is `(NonPromoItems - GiftItems)`

However When:

`ChildProducts` = `IEnumerable<IProductViewModel>[6]`
`PromoItems` = `IEnumerable<IProductViewModel>[1]` where item matches 1 item in `ChildProducts`
`GiftItems` = `IEnumerable<IProductViewModel>[0]`

My Result is

`NonPromoItems` = `IEnumerable<IProductViewModel>[5]` *This is Correct*
`NonGiftItems` = `IEnumerable<IProductViewModel>[4]` *This is Incorrect*

Somehow an `Except(...)` is removing an item when given an empty list to subtract.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can we see the comparer code?

Comment: There's the code, shouldn't matter since it's comparing `NonPromoItems` to `GiftItems` and `GiftItems` is empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the removed item a duplicate of another in the list? If so, this is standard behavior for the Except method call:

The Except<T> is a little tricky in that instead of returning the difference as you might expect, it instead returns the ***set*** difference. A mathematical set does not contain duplicates (e.g. HashSet).

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
int[] ints = { 3, 3, 3 };
var result = ints.Except(5); // result contains one element only: { 3 }
```

You can read more on [this CodeProject thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Feature/WickedCode.aspx?msg=3176445#xx3176445xx) in which I described the problem.

To get "Except"-like functionality while leaving duplicates, you can write the following line:

```
var ints = new [] { 3, 42, 3 };
var excluded = new [] { 42 };
var results = ints.Where(i => !excluded.Contains(i)); // returns { 3, 3 }
```

Comment: Yea, it is a dupe, know if there's a way to do the same linq operation but not remove distinct entries?